# Static Menu Bar in Web Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter project which has a drawer for the main navigation but, I am looking for a menu bar that will stay of the page without the ability to collapse it. This is being used for class navigation use and not page navigation. When they click on one of the navigation items it will take them to that class section. Does this exists or is this going to have to be a container filled with flatbuttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can crate a row and have expanded widget and use the left expanded widget as a drawer that's always open like this

```
Row(
 children: [
  Expanded(
   flex:2,
   child:Column(
    children:[
     //all drawer items here
    ],
   )
  ),
  Expanded(
    flex:4,
    child: Column(
      children:[
        //body section here
      ]
    )
   )
 ]
)
```